# Physics Body affects other nodes but node isn't moved

Tags: swift, xcode, sprite-kit

I'm creating the effect of a spinning wheel with pins that hit a pointer causing the wheel to slow down eventually. In the below paragraph, Node A is a pin on the edge of the spinning wheel and Node B is the 'ticker' that hits the pins, deflects out the way and by doing so slows the wheel a little.

I have two nodes, I need these nodes to collide which each other so that one can resist the motion of the other. Node A will hit Node B which has a `SKPhysicsJointSpring` attached. Without the `SKPhysicsJointSpring` Node A hits Node B and it moves out of the way correctly so I know that the nodes themselves are set up correctly. However when I introduce the `SKPhysicsJointSpring` I have a strange behaviour; the nodes react correctly with their physics bodies however the node itself doesn't move and therefore it appears as if Node A overlaps Node B before being resisted by Node B's physics body.

[image: Example of the node not moving]
<sub>(source: [gifyu.com](https://s5.gifyu.com/images/ezgif-7-6dcf19b11f43.gif))</sub>

The triangle (Node B) is pinned at the dark grey circle and the two blue lines are the spring joints. When the spring joints are removed the triangle is free to move and is hit but the circles on the edge of the wheel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the `SKPhysicsJointSpring` doesn't allow compression and therefore can never be smaller than the size it starts with! Replace with one spring joint in the middle of the ticker that extends when the ticker rotates works perfectly.